# SSRS: Value not to be grouped

Tags: reporting-services

I have a chart that currently has a count of cases, and then grouped by users, now I am trying to implement a second value which is a round up of all users and gives a global average.

this global average for obvious reasons cant be grouped based on the users in order to give the correct representation.

I am not using VS to output these reports but I using SQL report Builder 2008 R2.

Is there anyway that I can overcome this global avg being grouped by users, can I use a filer to stop this maybe?

Comment: Can you explain this a bit better, maybe using an image of the chart as it looks now and as you want it to look?

Answer (score 0):

The global average would be the number of cases divided by the number of distinct users. You can aggregate over the entire dataset by including the dataset name:

```
=Sum(Fields!Cases.Value, "MyDataset") / CountDistinct(Fields!User.Value, "MyDataset")
```

Comment: Not sure this is going to do it, I would be adding the above as an expression as another field, this would still be grouped by, which falls under the same problem, I guess what I am looking for is a conditional grouping, where I can exclude a field.

Comment: Sorry, when you said "global average" I assumed you wanted the average of all so you don't have the problems that appear when you try to have an average of averages.